# Cannot upload media files via Responsive File Manager

Tags: php, tinymce-4, responsive-filemanager

Recently I started using **Responsive File Manager** tool as a plugin on **TinyMCE**, and it looked perfect at first but after some time I'm having problem uploading files of media type (*mov*, *mpeg*, *m4v*, *mp4*, *avi*, *mpg*, *wma*, *flv*...) throws an error :

[image: Error thrown by the Responsive File manager]

> Just my opinion: 
>   I'm not good at complex level of programming but I think, maybe the
>   error is generated by the attempt to create a Thumbnail of the
>   uploading file (media type) so, is there any way to avoiding the
>   creation of Thumbnails for mov, mpeg, m4v, mp4, avi, mpg, wma, flv...?

If need some extra details about anything please make me know. "Thank you before hand".

Comment: I have the same problem. can anybody help us?

Answer (score 1):

add this line to **mime_type_lib.php**

```
'mp4' => 'video/mp4',
```

on line 100

this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open  filemanager/include/mime_type_lib.php and add `'mp4'     => 'video/mp4',` to the MIME types array. It will work.